# Samsung Galaxy S3 won't push emails

Tags: email, samsung-galaxy-s-3

I can only get new emails by manually doing a refresh.

I want instant access to emails, like in Blackberries.

I have both the Gmail and the Red Envelope emails with the same emails.

P.S. Is this a sync issue?

Comment: What do you mean by Red envelope? Is this the same as Gmail?

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked to see if sync is on? On ICS+ go to `Settings-Data Usage` and press the menu button, and ensure 'Auto Sync Data' is checked.

Then go to `Account-><select your account>` and ensure gmail, or email is selected.

Bear in mind that the email app can't push emails - it can only poll the server at a minimum of every 5 minutes.

If you're on less than ICS, then go to `System Settings->Accounts and Sync` and ensure sync is turned on. Select the account, and make sure gmail is checked.

Comment: thank you so much! I have been trying to figure this out for the longest now!! THANK YOU!!

Answer (score 0):

Try going to the Application Manager. Find Gmail and make sure that `show notifications` is checked. That fixed all of my problems.